# Data Transfer Out from “East US” to “East US 2”

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I have an storage account on "East US" and a VM on "East US 2".

The bandwidth "data transfer out" has cost between this regions? I know that the operations on the storage account has cost but If I download info from the VM to storage account has cost?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

East US and East US 2 are different regions. Inter-region bandwidth pricing applies. Presumably inexpensive tier, as not only are these on the same continent, they are in the same USA state.

Refer to your bill or a calculator for details, as pricing is [always changing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/upcoming-billing-changes-to-azure-bandwidth/).